# Magento not displaying error

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, magento

I am getting blank page instead of error message in the browser.
but i can view the error in the var/log/system.log

I have installed latest magento 1.8 CE.
I am using Ubuntu and my site's root is in /var/www/ chmoded 777. I have linked its alias to my home folder and working from it.

I haven uncommented the line on index.php.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

I renamed errors/local.xml.sample to local.xml.

Also I have added

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE “true”
```

to the .htaccess file.

Also i enabled log in developers panel in the configuration in the site's backend.

What to do so that i get the error messages in the browser.

Comment: check the permissions to `var` folder, not the `var/www`

Comment: i set chmod for /var to 777 still no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Open your project's index.php and find:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}

#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Add # in front of:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
```

and

```
}
```

Now remove # from below line:

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

After doing above steps, your code should look like:

```
#if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
#}

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Now delete cache folder under /var folder and refresh your page.

You should see error now.

Comment: I already did exactly as you said except deleting cache. but still no errors after deleting cache, only blank page displayed. I am frustrated. I am going to try it on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Open your index.php file nt the root of your site, and find line where:

```
#File: index.php

if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

So you can remove this `if( )`,  just set only`Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true)` during your debug, or turned on this mode from BO

Comment: i removed the if and set only Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); still no solved. how to do from BO?

Comment: I think if you rove if, it enought...HM.look for `var` folder permissions

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need "1" instead of "true", like so:

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to to this.

**Method 1:**
Open the file index.php (Magento Bootstrap file) and search for

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

Simply comment or # `if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {` and `}`, after this, remove # before `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` (It is just after mentioned if statement) In this way you have to comment, uncomment this **if statement** to enable or disable the Developer Mode.

**Method 2:**
Open **.htaccess** where your **index.php** is (*root of Magento Installation*) and put `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"` line anywhere in the file, better to put it at the top of the file. Now open the **index.php** file don't do anything, just uncomment (remove the # before) line `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. You can enable and disable developer mode from **.htaccess** file by setting the value of `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE` to **true** or **false**.

I will recommend second method.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to server redirection also.

Please check phpinfo output and check $_SERVER['REDIRECT_MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] variable also.

For Explanation:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/211417/38806